# "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." when trying to update from 20.04 to 23.04 due to broken package

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

I am trying to upgrade from 20.04 to the currently newest version 23.04.
however when I run the commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I noticed that the upgrade step has an "not upgraded" package.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Checking which package isnt upgraded i get a lutris package popping up.

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
lutris/focal,focal 0.5.12~ubuntu20.04.1 all [upgradable from: 0.5.11~ubuntu20.04.1]
lutris/now 0.5.11~ubuntu20.04.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 0.5.12~ubuntu20.04.1]
```

Now i don't need or want the lutris package, i tried to install it a while back but it turned out to be unsupported or something. But the package is broken, so i can't update it.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade  lutris
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lutris : Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.1 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

If possible i just want to remove it, but i don't know how. I already removed the lutris folder from the home directory and it is still showing up.

Comment: 20.04 doesn't upgrade to 23.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a PPA or external repo for lutris.

The clue is `lutris/now` where `now` isn't a standard Ubuntu repository section. You can confirm this with `apt-cache policy lutris` and paste the results in the question.

I'd remove lutris and reinstall after the upgrade.

`sudo apt remove lutris`